# Add UUID to Subscription Route Instead of User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, uuid

So I have a rails app that I'm developing that is a subscription service with Stripe.  When a user is created, they get assigned an :id and then if/when they purchase a subscription that gets assigned an :id.

The path for their account information, which is really not much there since it's Stripe looks something like this: 
https://myappnamehere.herokuapp.com/koudoku/users/47/subscriptions/2

So that's the 47th user and it's the 3rd subscription.

My questions are

1. Should I be using uuids with this app?
2. What's the best way to integrate uuids with this url structure?
3. What's involved in setting this up? Is this a simple routes.rb change?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: postgres with pg gem

Answer (score 1):

From the console run

```
 rails generate migration enable_uuid_ossp_extension
 rails generate model document title:string author:string
```

then edit your migration to look like this:

```
class EnableUuidOsspExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration


  def change
      enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'
    end
  end
```

Then edit the related Model migration or create a change migration to make your model use the new UUID

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration


def change
   create_table :documents, id: :uuid  do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :author
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then run:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

now you should be good to go.  One thing to keep in mind is that in order for your .first and .last methods to work you will have to create your own scopes to perform the query using the created_at timestamps.